# C++ -- vptr & vtbl associated with object or class?

Tags: c++

vptr -- virtual table pointer

vtbl -- virtual table

Question 1> Is it correct that vptr is associated with the object of a class?

Question 2> Is it correct that vtbl is associated with the class?

Question 3> How do they really work together?

Thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that `vptr` and `vtbl` are Implementation defined the C++ standard does not even talk about them. However, most known compilers implement dynamic dispatch through `vptr` and `vtbl`.

**Question 1: Is it correct that `vptr` is associated with the object of a class?**

**YES**
`vptr` is associated with the object of a Class which contains `Atleast one` virtual member function. The compiler adds Vptr to every object of the Class which is `Polymorphic`(contains atleast one virtual member function)The first 4 bytes of the `this` pointer then point to the `vptr`

**Question 2: Is it correct that `vtbl` is associated with the class?**

**YES**
`Vtbl` is associated with a Class. A `vtbl` gets created for each `Polymorphic` class.

**Question 3: How do they really work together?**

The compiler adds a `vptr` to every object of a Polymorphic class and also creates a `vtbl` for each of that class. The `vptr` points to the `vtbl`. The `vtbl` contains a list of addresses of all the virtual functions in that class. In case if a derived class overrides a virtual function of the Base Class then the address entry for that particular function in the `vtbl` is replaced by the address of the overridden function. At runtime the compiler traverses the `vtbl` of the particular class(Base or Derived) based on the address inside the pointer rather than the type of pointer and calls the function address in the `vtbl`. Thus **Dynamic Polymorphism** is achieved.
The cost of this dynamic polymorphism is:
`fetch`(fetch the vptr inside this) `fetch`(fetch the function address from list of functions in vtbl) `Call`(Call the function)

as against `call`(direct call to function since static binding).

Comment: Putting the `vptr` at the begin of the object is common, but not universal. In particular, when a polymorphic derived class has a non-polymorphic base class, the `vptr` might follow that base class subobject.

Answer (score 4):

The virtual table pointer is just a pointer inside every object of your class, pointing to the correct virtual table. Inside the virtual table are the addresses for the virtual functions of your class. The compiler traverses the virtual table to get the correct function when invoking a function through a base class pointer.